# Understanding the use of Lebesgue integrals

Tags: measure-theory, lebesgue-measure

I need some help to understand the following statement :

The space $L^2=L^2(S_1)$ where $S_1$ denotes the unit circle is the Hilbert space of all the square integrable functions on $S_1$,  with respect to Lebesgue measure, normalized so that the measure of the entire unit circle is 1.

It further goes on to say that the inner product is given by,

$(f,g)=\int_1^{2\pi}$ $f(e^{i\theta})\overline g(e^{i\theta}) d\theta$

where $d\theta$ is the ordinary  not normalized lebesgue measure on $[0,2\pi]$.

I understand the basic idea of the above statement, but i can't figure out what the

"with respect to lebesgue measure means ?" and the last line above i.e.

"$d\theta$ is the ordinary  not normalized lebesgue measure on $[0,2\pi]$." means ?

I am slightly confused, need some help.

Comment: The integral is defined over a measure, this one is taken over the lesbegue measure on $S^1$.

Answer (score 1):

It's just a fancy way to say it's the Lebesgue integral.

It's related to more generic definition of integration where the $dx$ at the end of the integral is in fact (or at least is associated with) a measure.

The Lebesgue measure (that is a measure of how big a set is) is what you get if you take the Lebesgue integral of the characteristic function:

$$m(E) = \int \chi_E dx = \int_E 1 dx$$